# Laravel Eloquent after save id becomes 0

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, save

It's a table migrated from https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

In the table `oauth_clients`, the field data type of id is varchar(40), not int.

```
$name = Input::get('name');
$id = str_random(40);
$secret = str_random(40);

$client = new oauthClient;
$client->name = $name;
$client->id = $id;
$client->secret = $secret;
$client->save();
```

After save(); the $client->id become '0', not the string I assigned.

That makes the following relation table save fail.

```
$endpoint = new OauthClientEndpoint(array('redirect_uri' => Input::get('redirect_uri));
$client->OauthClientEndpoint()->save($endpoint);
```

I checked the `$client->id`: after save, it becomes 0 and I get an error including this one:

```
(SQL: insert into `oauth_client_endpoints` (`redirect_uri`, `client_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (http://www.xxxxx.com, 0, 2014-09-01 11:10:16, 2014-09-01 11:10:16))
```

I manually saved an endpoint to prevent this error for now. But how do I resolve this issue?

Here's my model:

```
class OauthClient extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'oauth_clients';

  public function OauthClientEndpoint(){
    return $this->hasOne('OauthClientEndpoint', 'client_id', 'id');
  }

}

class OauthClientEndpoint extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'oauth_client_endpoints';
  protected $fillable = array('redirect_uri');

  public function OauthClient(){
    return $this->belongsTo('OauthClient', 'client_id', 'id');
  }

}

class CreateOauthClientsTable extends Migration {
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('id', 40);
      $table->string('secret', 40);
      $table->string('name');
      $table->timestamps();

      $table->unique('id');
      $table->unique(array('id', 'secret'));
    });
  }

  public function down() {
    Schema::drop('oauth_clients');
  }
}

class CreateOauthClientEndpointsTable extends Migration {
  public function up() {
    Schema::create('oauth_client_endpoints', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('client_id', 40);
      $table->string('redirect_uri');

      $table->timestamps();

      $table->foreign('client_id')
        ->references('id')->on('oauth_clients')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
  }

  public function down() {
    Schema::table('oauth_client_endpoints', function ($table) {
      $table->dropForeign('oauth_client_endpoints_client_id_foreign');
    });

    Schema::drop('oauth_client_endpoints');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your oauthClient model?

Comment: please provide the client model you created

Comment: Added models I created.

Comment: I figureout that add public $incrementing = false; in to model OauthClient then it resolved.

Answer (score 57):

When you are setting your own ID and not using auto_increment be sure to add `public $incrementing = false;` to that model. In your case you want:

```
class OauthClient extends Eloquent {

  public $incrementing = false;
  protected $table = 'oauth_clients';

  public function OauthClientEndpoint(){
    return $this->hasOne('OauthClientEndpoint', 'client_id', 'id');
  }

}
```

This is a tiny red block in the huge Laravel documentation:

> Note: Typically, your Eloquent models will have auto-incrementing keys. However, if you wish to specify your own keys, set the incrementing property on your model to false.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just spent 2 hours thinking what I was doing wrong.